# How to return latest record on criteria basis using QUERY() and FILTER() in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, formula

This should theoretically work, but I get an empty result. The columns are correct, but I'm not sure that the `where` clause is being applied correctly in conjunction with `QUERY()`.

```
=QUERY(
    FILTER('BD Financeiro'!A2:Y; 'BD Financeiro'!X2:X=1);
    "select Col1, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col20, Col5, Col8, Col10, 
    Col11, Col23, Col21, Col16, Col17, Col18, Col19, Col22 
    where Col6 = '"&max(
        FILTER('BD Financeiro'!F2:F; 'BD Financeiro'!X2:X=1))&"'
    ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. Just replaced "=" with "matches" in the where clause.

```
=QUERY(
    FILTER('BD Financeiro'!A2:Y; 'BD Financeiro'!X2:X=1);
    "select Col1, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col20, Col5, Col8, Col10, 
    Col11, Col23, Col21, Col16, Col17, Col18, Col19, Col22 
    where Col6 matches '"&max(
        FILTER('BD Financeiro'!F2:F; 'BD Financeiro'!X2:X=1))&"'
    ")
```

Ideally, one would expect "=" to work as well because MAX is expected to return just one value but for some reason it does not seem to work
with such formulas.